# How to sort based on a column with a one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, relationship, laravel-9

What I'm trying to do is this:

I have two tables with **One to Many** relationship

**sectors**

```
id
name
position
set_plan_id
```

**seat_plans**

```
id
name
order
```

I want to sort all **sectors** based on the ***order*** field present in **seat_plans** (which is of type numeric, so sort in ascending order).

I tried this code but I get unsorted sectors.

```
$sectors= Sector::whereHas('seat_plan', function ($query) {                                         
            $query->orderBy('order'); 
        })->get();
```

Can anyone kindly help me? thank you all

Comment: You can't use `orderBy` in `whereHas`; that function is used to determine if a relationship exists, but it doesn't actually return any records, so there is no reason to set an order. If you want to sort by a column on another table, you'd need to use `join()`, like `Sector::join('seat_plans', ...)->orderBy('seat_plans.order')->get()` (or similar; I forget the exact syntax, but you should be able to look it up and fill in the blanks)

Comment: I think Tim might be confusing the DB facade with the Eloquent ORM, but he's essentially right. It'd look like `DB::table('sector_table')->join('seat_plans'_table, 'sector_table.seat_plan_id', '=', 'seat_plans.id')->orderBy('seat_plans.order')->get()` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to do a join with the table like so:

```
$sectors = Sector::join('seat_plans', 'seat_plans.id', '=', 'sectors.seat_plan_id')
    ->orderBy('seat_plans.order')
    ->select('sectors.*')
    ->get();
```

Or make use of the aggregate method like shown below:

```
$sectors = Sector::withAggregate('seat_plan', 'order')
   ->orderBy('seat_plan_order')
   ->get();
```

reference: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_withAggregate

Comment: there is a small problem. I can't see sectors that don't have seat_plans. How can I fix this? I've considered the join for now.

Comment: @Sarah you mean retrieve also the sectors with no seat plans? in that case you'll have to use a leftJoin, Sector::leftJoin('seat_plans', 'seat_plans.id', '=', 'sectors.seat_plan_id')...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```php
Sector::select('sectors.*')
    ->join('seat_plans', 'seat_plans.id', 'sectors.seat_plans_id')
    ->orderBy('seat_plans.order')
    ->get();
```

for more approaches take a look at this [link](https://reinink.ca/articles/ordering-database-queries-by-relationship-columns-in-laravel).